# Navigation with post-count in Wordpress loop

Tags: wordpress, navigation

Navigation doesn't work with post-count using PHP conditional count in my Wordpress loop.

"next_posts" and "previous_posts" simply do not appear after the loop.

Here is my code. Hope you could help me and thank you in advance for that!

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
            <!-- Index Layout
            ================================================== -->
            <div id="content" role="main">
                <div class="column twelve" style="height: 430px;">
                    <div class="cover">
                        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/home.jpg" alt="" />
                    </div><!-- .cover -->
                </div><!-- .column -->
                <!-- Loop --> 
                <div class="column nine">
                    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
                    <?php $count = 0; ?>
                    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                    <?php $count++; ?>
                    <?php if ($count == 1) : ?>
                    <div class="column three">
                        <div class="cover">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail('small'); } else { ?><?php } ?></a>
                        </div><!-- .cover -->
                    </div><!-- .column -->
                    <div class="column three white">
                        <div class="vertical">
                            <div class="round">
                                <div class="time">
                                    <?php the_time('M') ?><br /><span><?php the_time('j') ?></span>
                                </div><!-- .time -->
                            </div><!-- .round -->
                                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(''); ?>"><?php the_title(''); ?></a></h2>
                                <div class="category">
                                    <?php the_category(''); ?>
                                </div><!-- .category -->
                        </div><div class="vertical-helper"></div><!-- .vertical -->
                    </div><!-- .column -->
                    <?php elseif($count == 2) : ?>
                    <div class="column three">
                        <div class="cover">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail('small'); } else { ?><?php } ?></a>
                        </div><!-- .cover -->
                    </div><!-- .column -->
                    <div class="column three black">
                        <div class="vertical">
                            <div class="round">
                                <div class="time">
                                    <?php the_time('M') ?><br /><span><?php the_time('j') ?></span>
                                </div><!-- .time -->
                            </div><!-- .round -->
                                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(''); ?>"><?php the_title(''); ?></a></h2>
                                <div class="category">
                                    <?php the_category(''); ?>
                                </div><!-- .category -->
                        </div><div class="vertical-helper"></div><!-- .vertical -->
                    </div><!-- .column -->
                    <?php elseif($count == 3) : ?>
                    <div class="column three">
                        <div class="cover">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail('small'); } else { ?><?php } ?></a>
                        </div><!-- .cover -->
                    </div><!-- .column -->
                    <div class="column three black">
                        <div class="vertical">
                            <div class="round">
                                <div class="time">
                                    <?php the_time('M') ?><br /><span><?php the_time('j') ?></span>
                                </div><!-- .time -->
                            </div><!-- .round -->
                                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(''); ?>"><?php the_title(''); ?></a></h2>
                                <div class="category">
                                    <?php the_category(''); ?>
                                </div><!-- .category -->
                        </div><div class="vertical-helper"></div><!-- .vertical -->
                    </div><!-- .column -->
                </div><!-- .column nine -->
                <div class="column three sidebar">
                    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/about.png" alt="" />
                    <h1>MOODYGUY est un magazine en ligne trans* identitaire. </h1>
                        <div class="round">
                            <div class="time">
                                Num<br /><span><?php $numposts = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish'");
if (0 < $numposts) $numposts = number_format($numposts); ?><?php echo $numposts ?></span>
                            </div><!-- .time -->
                        </div><!-- .round -->
                        <h2>Au sommaire :</h2>
                </div><!-- .column -->
                <?php elseif($count == 4) : ?>
                <div class="column six squarre">
                    <div class="cover">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail('squarre'); } else { ?><?php } ?></a>
                    </div><!-- .cover -->
                    <div class="column three white">
                        <div class="vertical">
                            <div class="round">
                                <div class="time">
                                    <?php the_time('M') ?><br /><span><?php the_time('j') ?></span>
                                </div><!-- .time -->
                            </div><!-- .round -->
                                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(''); ?>"><?php the_title(''); ?></a></h2>
                                <div class="category">
                                    <?php the_category(''); ?>
                                </div><!-- .category -->
                        </div><div class="vertical-helper"></div><!-- .vertical -->
                    </div><!-- .column -->
                </div><!-- .column -->
                <?php elseif($count == 5) : ?>
                <div class="column three">
                    <div class="cover">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail('small'); } else { ?><?php } ?></a>
                    </div><!-- .cover -->
                </div><!-- .column -->
                <div class="column three white">
                    <div class="vertical">
                        <div class="round">
                            <div class="time">
                                <?php the_time('M') ?><br /><span><?php the_time('j') ?></span>
                            </div><!-- .time -->
                        </div><!-- .round -->
                            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(''); ?>"><?php the_title(''); ?></a></h2>
                            <div class="category">
                                <?php the_category(''); ?>
                            </div><!-- .category -->
                    </div><div class="vertical-helper"></div><!-- .vertical -->
                </div><!-- .column -->
                <?php elseif($count == 6) : ?>
                <div class="column three black">
                    <div class="vertical">
                        <div class="round">
                            <div class="time">
                                <?php the_time('M') ?><br /><span><?php the_time('j') ?></span>
                            </div><!-- .time -->
                        </div><!-- .round -->
                            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(''); ?>"><?php the_title(''); ?></a></h2>
                            <div class="category">
                                <?php the_category(''); ?>
                            </div><!-- .category -->
                    </div><div class="vertical-helper"></div><!-- .vertical -->
                </div><!-- .column -->
                <div class="column three">
                    <div class="cover">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail('small'); } else { ?><?php } ?></a>
                    </div><!-- .cover -->
                </div><!-- .column -->
                <?php elseif($count == 7) : ?>
                <div class="column six squarre">
                    <div class="cover">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail('squarre'); } else { ?><?php } ?></a>
                    </div><!-- .cover -->
                    <div class="column three black">
                        <div class="vertical">
                            <div class="round">
                                <div class="time">
                                    <?php the_time('M') ?><br /><span><?php the_time('j') ?></span>
                                </div><!-- .time -->
                            </div><!-- .round -->
                                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(''); ?>"><?php the_title(''); ?></a></h2>
                                <div class="category">
                                    <?php the_category(''); ?>
                                </div><!-- .category -->
                        </div><div class="vertical-helper"></div><!-- .vertical -->
                    </div><!-- .column -->
                </div><!-- .column -->
                <?php elseif($count == 8) : ?>
                <div class="column three">
                    <div class="cover">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail('small'); } else { ?><?php } ?></a>
                    </div><!-- .cover -->
                </div><!-- .column -->
                <div class="column three black">
                    <div class="vertical">
                        <div class="round">
                            <div class="time">
                                <?php the_time('M') ?><br /><span><?php the_time('j') ?></span>
                            </div><!-- .time -->
                        </div><!-- .round -->
                            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(''); ?>"><?php the_title(''); ?></a></h2>
                            <div class="category">
                                <?php the_category(''); ?>
                            </div><!-- .category -->
                    </div><div class="vertical-helper"></div><!-- .vertical -->
                </div><!-- .column -->
                <?php elseif($count == 9) : ?>
                <div class="column three white">
                    <div class="vertical">
                        <div class="round">
                            <div class="time">
                                <?php the_time('M') ?><br /><span><?php the_time('j') ?></span>
                            </div><!-- .time -->
                        </div><!-- .round -->
                            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(''); ?>"><?php the_title(''); ?></a></h2>
                            <div class="category">
                                <?php the_category(''); ?>
                            </div><!-- .category -->
                    </div><div class="vertical-helper"></div><!-- .vertical -->
                </div><!-- .column -->
                <div class="column three">
                    <div class="cover">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail('small'); } else { ?><?php } ?></a>
                    </div><!-- .cover -->
                </div><!-- .column -->
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
                <?php else: endif; ?>
                <!-- End Loop -->
                <div class="column twelve">
                    <?php next_posts_link('<div>Older posts &#10093;</div>'); ?>
                    <?php previous_posts_link('<div>&#10092; Newer posts</div>'); ?>
                </div><!-- .column -->
            </div><!-- #content -->
            <!-- End Index
            ================================================== -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Suggestions:

- Remove `wp_reset_query();` located just above `next_posts_link`/`previous_posts_link` in your code. You don't want to reset the main query, before you call the navigation links.
- You actually don't need custom counter, because you can use  loop index `$GLOBALS['wp_query']->current_post` that starts from 0.
- Make sure your query is generating more than one page.
- Start with an empty loop and expand from there.

Hope this helps.

Comment: A big thank you, birgire! Thanks to your suggestions, I found what was wrong. It was very stupid : the number of posts to display configured in the "reading" section of the administration of the blog was higher than the one defined by my query. Now, it works perfectly. Thanks again!